# can not connect to to Postgres in heroku through pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, networking, heroku

I am trying to connect from my office network to the database that create in heroku (Postgres). I am using Pgadmin but the connection fail:

> could not connect to server:Connection timed out is the server running on host "ec2-54-204-43-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

but when I connect from my home this error doesn't exist so I think is a network issue that I have to resolve but I dont know what to see, just I disable my firewall but even that is not working .

Someone can know what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution. I talk with the Networking departmment and the problem was to able the ip and port where I needed to connect it in the firewall.